# How to use quotes on jsp page in <c:if /> tag

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

I have JSP page and on jsp page I have this:

```
<c:when test="${empty findAttributes && param.value1 != null}">

        <h1 align="center"><spring:message code="label.msg"/></h1>
</c:when>
```

instead of `param.value1 !=null` I have to use `param.value1 !=""`, but it does't work, gives me an error. Please help to bring it to correctness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way is using the `empty` keyword. This covers both nullness and emptiness.

```
<c:when test="${empty findAttributes && empty param.value1}">
```

Your condition would otherwise still fail if the parameter name `value1` is not supplied at all (which then evaluates to `null` not to empty string). A request parameter only evaluates to empty string when the parameter name is supplied without a value like so `value0=foo&value1=&value2=bar`. However, if the request parameter is totally absent like so `value0=foo&value2=bar` then it evaluates to `null` which isn't the same as an empty string.

Comment: Thanks, but my parameter won't absent at all. I have script inside <c:when> and it's trigger just when it's empty string... So I'm not expecting null and when it's null it will behave different How to be?

Comment: Request parameters are controllable by the enduser by simply manipulating the HTTP request. Empty string is not the same as null. When you use `empty`, both cases are covered.

Comment: Got you. Thank you BalusC

Answer (score 0):

You should use `empty` operator of JSTL instead of using  !=

```
<c:when test="${empty findAttributes && empty param.value1}">
```

From the 2.1 Spec:

To evaluate empty A:

- If A is null, return true,
- Otherwise, if A is the empty string, then return true.
- Otherwise, if A is an empty array, then return true.
- Otherwise, if A is an empty Map, return true
- Otherwise, if A is an empty Collection, return true,
- Otherwise return false.